# Can I watch pro/tournament matches from within the game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I like to watch LoL matches. But is there anyway to watch famous matches and tournaments live from within the game (not Twitch) ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean live, as they are played out?

Comment: @MCΔT yeah. and if its possible to hear the commentators as well.

Comment: I don't think so. I very well could be wrong, but I don't think the pro games are even over the Internet. I think they play on some sort of LAN.

Comment: of course they play on LAN. but I was just watching DOTA internationals yesterday. its LAN because its more stable. however there is a way to stream a LAN game to be watched through the server.

Comment: Also, I narrowed down the question to just League of Legends (might be a better fit for this site's Q&A style). Feel free to revert it if you'd prefer.

Comment: actually I am here to ask about LOL specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you have the professional player's official tournament account under your friend list, then you can just spectate them as per normal. Otherwise, No.

Comment: Unless you're on the Tournament Realm that wouldn't be possible either.